# Reading/Writing to w1 device [RPi]

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've been toying around with this [DS2433](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2433.pdf) chip (SO), trying to get it to connect to my Raspberry Pi. From what I've gathered, w1 devices are supposed to appear in `/sys/bus/w1/devices/` with a serial number in a format such as `28-xxxxxxxxxxxx`, however, I get several devices such as `00-400000000000` and `00-c00000000000`. I do not know if this is correct, but I doubt it is. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Pin layout is as follows:

```
 ___________                      ___________
|           | Pin 7              |           |
|           | (GPIO4) ----- DATA |_          |
|    RPi    |                     _| DS2433  |
|           | GND --------- GND  |           |
|___________|                    |___________|
```

Everything seems to be okay with the devices that are connected. I'm just confused as to why there is two. I have absolutely no idea how to read or write from this device, but I am doing some research. Any little bit helps. Thanks. Oh yeah, also, Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

Comment: I got odd numbers like that beginning 00 with a one-wire temp sensor that seems to be broken. Bought a couple of new ones and they work correctly. Can you try a different chip? Also have you got a pullup from the data line to 3V3 to improve the phantom power?

Comment: It was the pullup that I needed. I ran a wire from the 5v output through a 2.2k resistor and it worked like a charm.